# Error while compiling Spring boot maven poject

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Hi im learning Sping Boot and when I compile the maven project im getting the next error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) on project backweb-api: filtering `D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\src\main\resources\application-test.properties` to `D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\target\classes\application-test.properties` failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]

[Compile output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwuGN.png)

[application-test.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCQm8.png)

[Full trace mvn compile -3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Ver.png)

-I reviewed the application-test.properties file and I think that it's ok.
-I cleanned the target folders and re compiled maven project.

```html
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) on project backweb-api: filtering D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\src\main\resources\application-test.propert
ies to D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\target\classes\application-test.properties failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) on project backweb-api: filtering D:\***\***\backweb\backweb
-api\src\main\resources\application-test.properties to D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\target\classes\application-test.properties failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: filtering D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\src\main\resources\application-test.properties to D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\target\classes\application-test.p
roperties failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: filtering D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\src\main\resources\application-test.properties to D:\***\***\backweb\backweb-api\target\classes\applica
tion-test.properties failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:277)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException (CoderResult.java:274)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead (StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read (StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read (InputStreamReader.java:177)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1 (BufferedReader.java:211)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read (BufferedReader.java:287)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill (BufferedReader.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read (BufferedReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.BoundedReader.read (BoundedReader.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read (MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read (MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :backweb-api
```

Comment: Rerun the build (manually if required) with `-e` so you can get the full stacktrace so we can see what element is actually complaining (the file opener, parser, ...)

Comment: @HaroldH Hi :) I update the questing with fulltrace link. I had already reviewed it but I didn't understand the error either :(

Comment: It seems to be an issue with data read, maybe an encoding issue. 
Try to remove all values (not keys) from your properties files, and the comments too, and see if it helps.

By the way, please copy the code in the screenshoots as actual code, so it can be searchable by others

Comment: @HaroldH uncommenting application-test.properties my application works :0 thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **application-test.properties contains non-UTF8 characters** (e.g. the accent on the configuration o). This causes this error

Comment: yes that was the mistake thanks you HaroldH and @Bastian Hogne